# How much internal memory is available for APPs on a 32GB tablet

Tags: 4.4-kitkat

It is my understanding that 8 GB on a TABLET has 748mb available for apps and the rest dedicated for movies, music, documents etc. Of course there will be the boot, system OS stuff. 
Optionally there can be preloaded system apps which will count against the 748mb.

So I assume 32 GB would have 748mb X 4 or almost 3GB for applications. Is this correct ?

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly correct.
You only need to subtract the space required for the system once.
If you are on Android 4.4 you should have everything minus the system available for any purpose as apps, data and private files share the same storage.
Otherwise I assume around half of the available space can be used for apps and the rest for private data.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I remember running out of app space on Jelly Bean on an 8 GB tablet so they must have removed the memory partition restriction after that. On a Contixo Tablet, they had kitcat 4.4. When I looked at the memory available for apps under storage settings, it said 2.7 BG with a bare tablet. Any explanation for this.

Comment: There is the possibility of a mounted partition in `/data/media` (which is mirrored at `/sdcard`, `/storage/sdcard0` and other locations) which allows two distinct partitions for apps+data and private storage even on Android 4.4 Kitkat.

Comment: the internal memory part of 16 GB storage settings said only 2.7 GB. The sd card of another 16GB was taken into account in sd card section but listed no available space of apps as expected. I want all my apps on internal memory. can you point to ang google documents that discuss when they took the restriction off what memory  apps can use.

Comment: also bear in mind that i use virtually no storage memory. it's there but useless.

Comment: Mystery solved

The real explanation to this mystery is: The playstore app on android 4.2 was somehow broken.

It probably didn't release internal memory space after the download and install. Hence the space ran out. Lot of people complained about this insufficient memory. There was more than one problem causing it. Even Google results about this problem didn't show up for a long time until recently. Even other forums didn't know about the problem.

Since it was my first real tablet and googling didn't get any results to enlighten me so i assumed it was an android limitation.